# i cant pass value to summernote using id

Tags: javascript

This is my java scripte code but i cant pass value to summernote using id i want to pass pree value to the summernote to be edited but nothing is displayed

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
            var table = document.getElementById('hotel');
            var markupStr;
            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
                table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                {
                     //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                     document.getElementById("id").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("hotel_name").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                   
                     document.getElementById("location").value = this.cells[9].innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("rate").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("lno").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("uno").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
                   
                   // document.getElementById("sumsummernote7781").value = this.cells[7].innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("acce").value = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
                     //var markupStr = this.cells[7].innerHTML;
                  
   
                   //$('#summernote7781').summernote('code', markupStr);
                };
               
   

            }

           
                   
 });
     </script>
```